# Problem with fancyhdr printing the wrong section title

Tags: biblatex, fancyhdr, appendices

I have a problem with `fancyhdr` in combination with the `appendix` package. The problem occurs - as far as I have observed it so far - only when I compile a one-page document. In `twoside` mode everything seems to compile correctly.

As you can see in the MWE, the headline of the main section is on each page. On the bibliography page, the title is also in the header. However, it remains there for the following pages in the document, although the attachments have their own title.

In `twoside` mode this is not the case.

Do I have a bug in my code, or is this a bug in the `fancyhdr` or `appendix` package?

I am very grateful for any help.

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% \documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[titletoc, title, header]{appendix}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{%
    a4paper,%
    top = 3cm,%
    bottom = 3.5cm,%
    inner = 2.5cm,%
    outer = 2.5cm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    showframe = false%
}

\fancypagestyle{general}{%
    \fancyhf{}                  % Clean fields
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \fancyhead[R]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

\let\printbibliographyCopy\printbibliography
\renewcommand{\printbibliography}{%
    \cleardoublepage%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}%
    \pagenumbering{Roman}%
    \printbibliographyCopy%
    \cleardoublepage%
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \let\oldSection\section%
    \renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
        \cleardoublepage%
        \oldSection{#1}%
    }%
}

\title{\texttt{fancyhdr} issue}
\author{Sam}
\date{}

\bibliography{refs}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{general}%
    \pagestyle{general}%

    \maketitle

    \section{\lipsum[1][1]}
    \lipsum[1-3]

    \subsection{\lipsum[1][2]}
    \lipsum[4-6]

    \subsection{\lipsum[1][3]}
    \lipsum[7-10]

    \section{\lipsum[2][1]}
    \lipsum[1-3]

    \subsection{\lipsum[2][2]}
    \lipsum[4-6]

    \subsection{\lipsum[2][3]}
    \lipsum[7-10]

    \section{\lipsum[3][1]}
    \lipsum[1-3]

    \subsection{\lipsum[3][2]}
    \lipsum[4-6]

    \subsection{\lipsum[3][3]}
    \lipsum[7-13]\cite{Nobody06}

    \printbibliography

    \begin{appendices}
        \section{\lipsum[4][1]}
        \lipsum[1-3]

        \section{\lipsum[5][1]}
        \lipsum[1-3]

        \section{\lipsum[6][1]}
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

---

### Screenshots

**Normal section in `oneside` or `twoside` mode**
[image: Normal Section]

---

**References in `oneside` or `twoside` mode**
[image: References]

---

**Appendix in `twoside` mode**
[image: Appendix in twoside mode]

---

**Appendix in `oneside` mode**
[image: Appendix in oneside mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same effect can be reproduced in the following simplified MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[titletoc, title, header]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\fancypagestyle{general}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}
\pagestyle{general}%

\begin{document}
  \section{\lipsum[1][1]}
  \lipsum[1-3]

  \begin{appendices}
    \section{\lipsum[4][1]}
    \lipsum[1-3]
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The issue specifically lies with the option `header` passed to `appendix`. The option is described in the manual as

> Adds a name (e.g., ‘Appendix’) before each appendix in page headers. The name is given by the value of `\appendixname`. Note that this is the default behaviour for classes that have chapters.

If the option is enabled, `\sectionmark` will be redefined as follows at the beginning of the `appendices` environment

```
\def\sectionmark##1{%
  \if@twoside
    \markboth{\@formatsecmark@pp{#1}}{}
  \else
    \markright{\@formatsecmark@pp{#1}}{}
  \fi}
```

Note how the definition differs between `twoside` and `oneside`. This definition is consistent with the usual definitions in `article.cls`.

When `fancyhdr` is loaded, the definition of `\sectionmark` in `article`-like classes always involves only `\markboth` regardless of the `twoside`/`oneside` setting. It always is

```
\def\sectionmark##1{%
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
      \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
    \fi
    ##1}}{}
```

The simple solution is not to use the `header` option of `appendix`, since it was apparently not written with the idiosyncrasies of `fancyhdr` in mind. Then you won't see the *Appendix* in the header, though. If you want to retain that, you can patch `appendices` when `fancyhdr` is loaded.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[titletoc, title, header]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\fancypagestyle{general}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}
\pagestyle{general}%

% patch appendices for fancyhdr
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{fancyhdr}
  {\apptocmd\appendices{%
     \if@chapter@pp
     \else
       \if@dohead@pp
         \def\sectionmark#1{\markboth{\@formatsecmark@pp{#1}}{}}%
       \fi
     \fi}}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{\lipsum[1][1]}
  \lipsum[1-3]

  \begin{appendices}
    \section{\lipsum[4][1]}
    \lipsum[1-3]
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: Header shows "Appendix A Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum."]

Comment: Thank you very much moewe! Works like a charm. Could you please be so kind to shortly explain what `\if@chapter@pp`, `\if@dohead@pp` and `\@formatsecmark@pp` mean (and do)? I really do not find very much about these commands. Do you know a good resource to learn these kinds of things?

Comment: @Sam Those are all internal commands whose meaning I (hopefully correctly) picked up from reading the `appendix.sty` source. `\if@chapter@pp` is true when the appendices are set as `\chapter`s (which is not the case with the `article` class), `\if@dohead@pp` is true when the `header` option is used and `\@formatsecmark@pp` is an internal macro used to format the running head. I just analysed the code in `appendix.sty` redefining `\sectionmark` and replicated the tests for the relevant cases.